# Old Garbage Collection gets filled and doesn't clean, probably because of Indexing

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jms, hibernate-search, infinispan

Recently, I tried to use Hibernate Search indexing and I'm working in order to find a stable solution for a production environment. The case is in a wildfly 10 AS I am using indexing using a HibernateOGM PersistenceContext. This automatically adds data to index(Infinispan file-cache-store).

The problem is that I have an MDB consuming data from a JMS queue and I need in on call of this function(onMessage, one queue entry contains around 1 million entities - big requests) to persist around 1 million entities and publish them to another AMQP queue via a stateless EJB.

While persisting and publishing, I noticed that after a specific amount of time major gc cannot happen and after old gen gets full, eden space becomes also and there is a strong degrade in the rate of persisting and publishing messages.

My thoughts are that the onMessage function needs a transaction and until it finishes it keeps all the data in memory or something(indexing or persisted data) and can't just clean the old gen in order to be able to rollback.

I provide some monitoring pictures. You can easily see that suddenly after both spaces of memory(old gen and eden) are full and trying to go empty, there is a strong degrade at the rate of publishing messages to the other queue(it's like I create one by one entities from a list that comes as a request from the jms, I persist them and publish them in a for loop to a rabbitmq queue). Is there any way to keep index always on disk with infinispan if that's the case? Already tried minimum value at eviction, small chunk size etc. Didn't work well. Also tried to change GC algorithms but I end up always in the same situtation. Maybe another infinispan persistent file store implementation? I use single-file-cache-store for now and used soft-index cache store before. Any suggestions-thoughts?

Thanks

Hibernate Search 5.6.1, Infinispan 8.2.4, Hibernate OGM 5.1, Wildfly 10

[VisualGC from visualVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LznKH.png)

[VisualVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEirb.png)

[RabbitMQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xxz8.png)

[JMS Threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxk1W.png)

[Hibernate Search Sync Thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz32D.png)

Comment: The best thing to in situations like this is to get a heap dump (e.g. `jmap -dump:format=b,file=<file_name> <pid>`) and then use tools like Eclipse MAT to analyse and see what's up.

Comment: I tried to upgrade first versions first, and I'm going to check it now. I only used the visualizations of visualvm and visualgc till now. Never heard of eclipse MAT. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Infinispan (9.2) is able to store data "off heap" so the short answer is yes it's possible. But consider the big picture before choosing to do that, not all scenarious benefit from off heap storage as this depends on a number of factors.

Infinispan by definition is meant to buffer hottest data in memory, by default "on heap" as that will help your overall performance when it's just Java objects as you can then skip (de)serialization overhead; you need to tune your heap sizes to accomodate for the load you are planning, it can not do that automatically. The easiest strategy is to observe it with similar tools under load when enabling a very generous heap size and then trim it down to a reasonable size you know will work for your load.

So try to verify first if you're not just having a too small heap for its peak operation requirements before suspecting a leak or an unbounded growth. If there actually is an actual leak, you might first want to try upgrading as those versions are quite old - a lot of issues have been fixed already.

Comment: I really want to upgrade all the modules but I already spent much time dealing with version errors in order to make it work. I just used the feature-packs for orm and engine again today but the fact that I need ogm also maybe is the problem. I am still getting random errors like     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/hibernate/search/jsr352/logging/impl/Log (Module \"deployment.test.war:main\" from Service Module Loader): org/hibernate/search/util/logging/impl/BaseHibernateSearchLogger"}.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about 9.2. Also your strategy works well, followed it today too but in that case I'll need a big ram to feel safe about peak requirements. It would be better if the system could take a big pause to evict during onMessage call and clean old gen space, and continue publishing instead of trying to find small time frames to clean a little bit until full again. Thank you Sanne.